# Creating a SQL query for matching a varchar field using a given list of words

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a piece of advice in creating a SQL query. I have a MySQL database with a VARCHAR(255) field called 'sentences'. As you can guess this field contains a sentence of several words. I want to query the database to retrieve any combination of a few given words but without any other words.

Here comes an example: let's say I want to get every combination of '**do**', '**you**', '**like**', '**tea**'. So I would like to have in my result the sentences: '**do you like tea**', '**do you like**', or '**like tea**' or '**do tea**' but not the sentences '**do you like coffee**', '**do you fancy tea**'

Of course, I could create all possible combinations of words with PHP for example and then create the right SQL query. But I am looking for a way to do so only using SQL operators and the given words, without any other pre-processing.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: What happens if the sentence was *do you hate tea and like coffee*?

Comment: if you are talking about the input, all of the suggested results should be returned except 'do you fancy tea' because fancy is not in the input. If your sentence is a row in the dabatabe, it should not be returned because coffe is not in the input.

Comment: Ignore my previous (deleted) comment. Seems like the scenario can be explained via [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory). I am thinking.

Comment: Is it possible for you to store individual words of a sentence as rows in another table?

Comment: I am not sure but may be you can have the a table with four rows `do, you, like, tea` joined with `sentence_words` table grouped by sentence_id. The sentences whose word count is *equal to* the matching rows count will be returned. I am sorry I am unable to describe it in words, but I can explain with PHP code if that helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to auto-set search for **'do you like'** and **'do you like tea'** but not **'do you like coffe'**, I think it's impossible, because for search engine it's just a string of characters. it doesn't know the difference betwwen 'tea' and 'coffe' other than length (3 vs 5) and character set

PS
for searching multiple strings try using [fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you use

```
WHERE (field LIKE '%do%%like%%tea%')
```

then your given examples work, but you rely on the given order, so a value "like tea do" would not be covered.

I would guess solution would be to form the query like:

```
WHERE (field LIKE '%do%') AND (field LIKE '%like') AND (field LIKE '%tea%')
```